# Regex to get everything between two characters starting at a character

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

We have this really weird string here:

```
re'\gfby  by  A »;ŸÎ                 \     l o l l i .
p o p - c o l \ n t u s e r . d a t   dŸŸœ~®ã€º &¹UÚÂdŸŸœ~®ã€º
&¹UÚÂ    eŸŸœ~®ã€º &¹UÚÂrmtmÖpïJÔ
```

we want to find

```
l o l l i . p o p
```

So we want to find the first `"."` in the string, then get everything left of the dot until we run into any of:

- Backslash "\"
- Dash "-"
- Two Spaces "\s\s"
- The Start or End of the String "^ or $"

And everything right of the dot with the same rules, here is another test case:

`\ n t u s e r . d a t   dŸŸœ~®ã€º`

should return

`n t u s e r . d a t`

We were experimenting with lookarounds in this expresssion :

`(?<=\\|\s\s)(\.)(?=\\|\s\s)`

And we also experimented with this:

`(\\|\s\s|-)(.*?)(\.)(.*?)(\\|\s\s|-)`

Our problem with this expression is that regex first looks at the left hand argument and matches it to the earliest match in the string, we want regex to instead start looking at the . and then go left/right until it hits one of our breaks.

Thanks!

Comment: We have also experimented with this 
(\\|\s\s|-)(.*?)(\.)(.*?)(\\|\s\s|-)

Comment: Hmm, if you stop looking after the first dot, then 'lolli.pop' won't match.

Comment: Please format your question better and include the exact input and expected result.

Comment: Maybe `^.*?((?:(?!\s\s|[.\\-]).)+\.(?:(?!\s\s|[.\\-]).)+)` [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/EhKFyO/2)

Comment: Sorry about that, i was half way through writing the question when i pressed post, here it is with better information, thanks!

Comment: A general thing to keep in mind: Regex only goes forward. You can't match backwards, i.e. *"Start at the dot and take everything to the left until X"* is not how it works. It helps to adopt a mindset of "find match candidates and discard them when a condition turns out to be unfulfilled later in the string". In this case, "any character that is not one of the delimiters" is a good way to find match candidates that you can match forward from.

Comment: @Tomalak Yeah, your solution works for me perfectly, and i think i understand where i was going wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In

```
re'\gfby  by  A »;ŸÎ                 \     l o l l i .
p o p - c o l \ n t u s e r . d a t   dŸŸœ~®ã€º &¹UÚÂdŸŸœ~®ã€º
&¹UÚÂ    eŸŸœ~®ã€º &¹UÚÂrmtmÖpïJÔ
```

this

```
(?:(?!  )[^\\.-])+\.(?:(?!  )[^\\.-])+
```

finds

```
 l o l l i .
p o p
```

and

```
 n t u s e r . d a t
```

Breakdown:

```
(?:           # begin non-capturing group
  (?!  )      #   look-ahead: any position not followed by two spaces
  [^\\.-]     #   any character except '\', '.', and `-`
)+            # end group, repeat at least once
\.            # a '.'
(?:           # \
  (?!  )      #  |-- exactly the same as above
  [^\\.-]     #  |
)+            # /
```

- Use `*` instead of `+` if you want to allow matches that start or end with a dot.
- Single spaces are valid parts of the match, so they might occur at the start or end with this (in the above sample, they do). Trim the result if needed.
- Since the matching is done by a negated character class, we get the side conditions "...or the start/end of the string" and "include newlines" for free.

Answer (score 0):

To find the first "." in the string, then get everything left of the dot until you encounter one of your requirements, you might use:

`^.*?((?:(?!\s\s|[.\\-]).)+\.(?:(?!\s\s|[.\\-]).)+)`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/4cgRzs/1)

Your match will be in the first capturing group.

**Explanation**

- `^` Assert the start of the string
- `.*?` Match any character zero or more times non greedy so give up as least as possible
- `(` Capturing group

  - `(?:` Non capturing group

    - `(?!\s\s|[.\\-]).` Negative lookahead to assert that what is on the right side are not two whitespace characters or a dot, backslash or hyphen
  - `)+` Close non capturing groupmore times
  - `\.` Match a dot literally
  - `(?:` Non capturing group

    - `(?!\s\s|[.\\-]).` Negative lookahead to assert that what is on the right side are not two whitespace characters or a dot, backslash or hyphen
  - `)+` Close non capturing grouphyphen and repeat that one or more times
- `)` Close capturing group